# How to update wp_wc_product_attributes_lookup table after running update_post_meta?

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am using the following code to add attributes to a product:

```
$product_attr = get_post_meta(2, '_product_attributes',true);
      
      $product_attr["pa_product-type"] = [
        'name' => "pa_product-type",
        'value' => '',
        'is_visible' => '0',
        'is_taxonomy' => '1'
        ];  
        
    wp_set_object_terms(2, "Caps", pa_product-type , true );
    update_post_meta(2, '_product_attributes', $product_attr);
```

The attribute is getting updated successfully in the product and is showing up in product edit page. However, the attribute value is not getting updated in `wp_wc_product_attributes_lookup` table. How to trigger update in this table after updating/adding attributes using the above code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very interesting question!

The `wp_wc_product_attributes_lookup` table is used to improve WooCommerce performance and it's normally updated automatically. There is a class `DataRegenerator` that handles the product attributes regeneration process. But if you change the attributes directly in the `wp_postmeta` like this:

```
    $product_id = 46;
    $product_attr = get_post_meta($product_id, '_product_attributes',true);

    $product_attr["pa_color"] = [
        'name' => "pa_color",
        'value' => '',
        'is_visible' => '0',
        'is_taxonomy' => '1'
    ];

    wp_set_object_terms($product_id, "Blue", 'pa_color' , true );
    update_post_meta($product_id, '_product_attributes', $product_attr);
```

then the `wp_wc_product_attributes_lookup` table is not updated immediately.

But you can trigger this update manually by using `LookupDataStore` class.

First you add

```
use Automattic\WooCommerce\Internal\ProductAttributesLookup\LookupDataStore;
```

outside your function, for example on the top of the plugin or theme php file or just above your `add_action` line.

Then you can call the function to create product attributes in the lookup table for a specific `product_id`

```
    $lookupDataStore = new LookupDataStore();
    $lookupDataStore->create_data_for_product($product_id);
```

[Source](https://bytflow.com/how-to-update-woocommerce-wp_wc_product_attributes_lookup-table-programatically/)